# Appwrite + React :Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: reactjs, cors, cross-domain

Am trying pull data from appwrite but am getting CORs error.
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [https://cloud.appwrite.io.v1/databases/{databaseId}/collections/{collectionId}/documents](https://cloud.appwrite.io.v1/databases/%7BdatabaseId%7D/collections/%7BcollectionId%7D/documents). (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)

how do i resolve this in react or appwrite dashboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CORS errors when working with Appwrite can be caused by a number of reasons. Here's a list of things that you can try, and see if any of them works:

- Make sure you have added your client-side app as a **platform** in the appwrite dashboard.
- Make sure that the **Hostname** is set correctly in the platform. If your client-side app is hosted on `https://subdomain.example.com`, the hostname you should use is `subdomain.example.com`.
- Make sure you're initializing your client with the correct Project ID, and endpoint: [reference](https://appwrite.io/docs/getting-started-for-web#initSDK)

Make sure you try all the suggestions, and let me know if you face any issues :)